# how to send the html form value in js page to use in another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to send the value of GST to order.js file if and only if the value of VAT mode is selected to be "with Vat" form the page new_order.php

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="vat" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" onChange="getVatMode(this.value);" align="right">VAT Mode</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select name="vatMode" value="data" class="form-control" id="vatMode" required="required">
<option value="1">Without VAT</option>
 <option value="2">With VAT</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
<label for="gst" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" align="right">GST (13%)</label>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <input type="text" readonly name="gst" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="gst" required/>
 </div>
 </div>
```

and I need to pass this value of VAT to be passed to order.js page without loading for calculation of sum

```
function calculate(dis,paid){
        var sub_total = 0;
        var gst = 0;
        var net_total = 0;
        var discount = dis;
        var paid_amt = paid;
        var due = 0;
        $(".amt").each(function(){
            sub_total = sub_total + ($(this).html() * 1);
        })
        gst = Math.round(0.13 * sub_total);
        net_total = gst + sub_total;
        net_total = net_total - discount;
        due = net_total - paid_amt;
        $("#gst").val(gst);
        $("#sub_total").val(sub_total);

        $("#discount").val(discount);
        $("#net_total").val(net_total);
        //$("#paid")
        $("#due").val(due);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can use `$("#YourFormId").serialize()`:

```
$("form").on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serialize());
});
```

**For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute**

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/